# wrap text around img, when put the img at the middle of <p>

Tags: css, word-wrap

When putting the img at the middle of `<p>`, text can not wrap around the img.
Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        *{
            margin:0;
            padding:0;}
        div{
            width:500px;

        }
        p{
            font-size: 30px;
            word-break:break-all;
            display: inline;

        }
        span{
            font-size: 50px;
            color:yellow;
        }
        img{
            width: 30px;
            height: 80px;
            display: inline-block;
            float: right;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div>

    <span>Fro</span>
    <p>Frontend FrontendFrontendFrontend FrontendFronFrontendFrontendFrontend FrontendFronFrontendFrontendFrontend FrontendFronFrontendFrontendFrontend FrontendFronFrontendFrontendFrontend<img src="" alt="img">FrontendFronFrontendFrontendFrontend FrontendFronFrontendFrontendFrontend FrontendFronFrontendFrontendFrontend FrontendFronFrontendFrontendFrontend FrontendFronFrontendFrontendFrontend FrontendFronFrontendFrontendFrontend FrontendFronFrontendFrontendFrontend FrontendFronFrontendFrontendFrontend FrontendFronFrontendFrontendFrontend FrontendFron/p>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

and it look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W4Qag.jpg).

So how to let the text wrap around the left side of the img???
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

(edited)

Just erase the `display: inline-block` from your `img` rule and also erase `display:inline;` from the `p` tag (both don't make sense):
.

```
img {
  width: 30px;
  height: 80px;
  float: right;
}
p {
   font-size: 30px;
   word-break:break-all;
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XKjpqM

Comment: That might have had to do with the fact that you example text consisted of *one* very long word, which is unrealistic. I changed that now in my example (same settings otherwise) - please have a look: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GqjYby